# Sending HTTP requests to controller from statics

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

I'm working with Spring Boot app. I have a `resources/static/index.html` page with the following ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/create',
    data: {content: content}
});
```

I execute it when buttton is clicked and when I click it I'm getting the following URL in the address bar:

```
http://localhost:8080/?content=newPaste
```

For some reason `/create` is lost. Why so? And what is the right way to specify the URL in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data as a string. Try this approach:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '/create',
   contentType: "application/json",
   dataType : 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify({content: content})
});
```